# Need pointers to get started with using Markdown as an instruction builder

Tags: python, html, markdown

I have been using *Stackoverflow* and *IPython Notebook* for a while now and have become really fond of the **Markdown** editors (especially the feature in SO that shows the output as-you-write).

I'm used to using `Python` and haven't dealt with `HTML`, `javascript`, `CSS` etc since it's a big lump to swallow - for my needs. But I would really like to get some pointers on how to get started if I want to build something like this:

[image]

As you can se this layout will allow me to easy built instructions were I tell people to write the bold text in the underlined fields.

*Bonus info*

As you might guess I would like to be able to physical print out the steps and outputs [on A4] so I can do manual writing

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you building a web page (HTML & JavaScript), or a native GUI app? And how does Python play into it all?

Comment: I would like to build what is most easy to build - whether it is a webpage or a native GUI app. Python doesn't play into it - I'm just saying that this language I know and used to (perhaps somebody knows some python modules that will allow me to do it). But I'm saying that I'm willing to learn new languages/systems in order to build a program that has this behavior.

Comment: There are tons of beginners HTML sites and books - but I don't want to build a company webpage. I want to build something just as usefull as IPython.

Answer (score 3):

You want to have a printed fill-in-the-blank text?

Use a css workaround with white font color on white background and a border at the bottom: http://jsfiddle.net/G7HvL/

With [mediatypes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) this will be only done on print:

```
@media screen {
    strong {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
}
```

But this will change **all** strong tags, so I would use at least a combination with ***bold and italic*** or **`bold code`**

And on screens users can unhide the text by marking it with the mouse.

Comment: Wow.. thank you very much. This is a good pointer.

Comment: I then guess I could use somthing like [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/) or [wk<html>toPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) - both have python wrappers

Comment: is it possible to make you code so you get both outputs from the same html source code. So if I write a line like `this is an <strong>example</strong>`. Then I will get both "this is an **example**" AND "this is an **___________**"

Comment: How do you want to switch beetween these both versions? Clientside with JS or jQuery. Or with a server variable.

Comment: Was thinking of a server side variable.

Comment: Just wrap your construct in a server side switchable class e.g. 'fill-in-the-blank' and cascade the css workaround.

    <div class="fill-in-the-blank">
    this is an em <em>example</em>.
    </div>

I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7HvL/).

Comment: the __updated__ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7HvL/6/)

Comment: Thx for the answer. It was however not exactly what I wanted.. Was looking for a way to define a variable that contained the html, but then I could apply different styles to the variable. I think the solution would be similar to embedding a navigation bar -  twice and then add different styles.

Comment: BTW I have decided to learn HTML5, CSS3 and basic JS since your example showed me that I can reach the solution fairly simple this way.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding printing, you might want to look at [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html), which can (among others) convert Markdown to PDF documents (via LaTeX, so the typographic quality of the output will be nice).

Comment: What would be most stable - converting markdown to pdf or html to pdf?